# How to write the set of possible pairs of $p$, $q$ with additional conditions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have the integer variables $p$ and $q$ such that $p, q \in [0,2]$.

**Question.**

How to write the set of possible pairs of $p$, $q$ if $p$ and $q$ can take integer values from the range $[0,2]$ and they aren't equal to $0$ together?

**Update:**
I hope, my set is $\{(1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (0,1), (0,2), (2,0),(2,1), (2,2)\}$

**My attemp is:**
$\{(p, q) \in \mathbb N: 0 \le p, q \le 2, p \neq 0 ~\text{and}~ q \neq 0\}$

Comment: Your attempt is almost fine. You should write "or" instead of "and" though. You could also write $p+q\neq 0$ to make it shorter.
Also, you forgot $(2,0)$ in your set.

Comment: The last clause should be $p \neq 0 \lor q \neq 0$, as this is the negation of $p =0 \land q=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nearly perfect, but the last part ($p \ne 0$ and $q \ne 0$) is slightly incorrect. Really it should say $p + q \ne 0$ because $2 + 0 = 2$ even though in that case, $q$ is $0$.

Comment: Why did you write $\pm$?

Comment: @martin.koeberl I have no idea...